# Stuck on Flask tutorial Step 5 "initdb" not recognized

Tags: python, flask

I have read this issue (https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1902) and this issue (https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1902) as well as compared line by line with the example project on Github. I cannot find a solution.

When I run

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr
flask initdb
```

I get this error:

```
Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Error: No such command "initdb".
```

initdb:

```
def init_db():
    db = get_db()
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
    db.commit()

@app.cli.command('init_db')
def initdb_command():
    init_db()
    print("Initialized the database.")
```

Any ideas?

Things I have tried:

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr
```

made sure to update with `pip install https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tarball/master`

Comment: What does your `initdb` custom command code block look like?

Comment: @glibdud see edit

Comment: Please post that in the question, but I'm looking for the function that is preceded by `@app.cli.command('initdb')`.

Comment: @glibdud added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've called your custom command `init_db`:

```
@app.cli.command('init_db')
```

Therefore to run it, you'll need to use:

```
flask init_db
```

Comment: Ugh. I hate dumb typo errors that I don't catch before posting here. Thank you. Sorry to bother.